# Strange behavior in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a Home page where I display set of data fetched from a $http.get function.

Well, the first time the page loads, it's displayed perfectly, but if you reload the page, it arises the following error:

> angular.js:13550 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 695
>       at Object.parse (native)

Now, if I go to another page and come back to Home page, it works fine. And if I reload again, it arises the same error.

I'm struggling trying to guess what's happening.

Here I post the init function:

```
   $scope.init = function() {
      functions.loading($scope.loading, true);
      $scope.$on('loading', function(evt, value) {
          $scope.loading.state = value;
      });
      angular.element(document).ready(function () {
          searchService.search_stats().then( function(response) {
              FusionCharts.ready(function(){
                  var last7days = new FusionCharts({
                    "type": "column2d",
                    "renderAt": "last7days",
                    "width": "100%",
                    "height": "300",
                    "dataFormat": "json",
                    "dataSource": {
                      "chart": {
                          "caption": "Volume of Searches - Graph",
                          "subCaption": "Last 7 days",
                          "xAxisName": "Last 7 days",
                          "yAxisName": "Volume of searches",
                          "theme": "fint"
                       },
                      "data": response.data.last7days
                    }
                  });
                  last7days.render();

                  var search_countries = new FusionCharts({
                      "type": "maps/world",
                      "renderAt": "search_countries",
                      "width": "100%",
                      "height": "400",
                      "dataFormat": "json",
                      "dataSource": {
                          "chart": {
                              "caption": "Search Volume by Country - Graph",
                              "subcaption": "Last 7 days ",
                              "entityFillHoverColor": "#cccccc",
                              "numberScaleValue": "1,1000,1000",
                              "numberScaleUnit": "K,M,B",
                              "numberPrefix": "$",
                              "showLabels": "1",
                              "theme": "fint"
                          },
                          "colorrange": {
                              "minvalue": "0",
                              "startlabel": "Low",
                              "endlabel": "High",
                              "code": "#e44a00",
                              "gradient": "1",
                              "color": [
                                  {
                                      "maxvalue": response.data.max/2,
                                      "displayvalue": "Average",
                                      "code": "#f8bd19"
                                  },
                                  {
                                      "maxvalue": response.data.max,
                                      "code": "#6baa01"
                                  }
                              ]
                          },
                          "data": response.data.countries
                      }
                  });
                  search_countries.render();
                  functions.loading($scope.loading, false);
              });
          });
          functions.containerResize();
      });
```

**search_stats** is in a Factory:

```
      search_stats: function(a) {
          return $http.get('/api/myFunctions/search_stats/', {cache:false});
      }
```

Any idea?

Comment: Open your browser dev tools, click on the network panel, and look what actual JSON is being downloaded.

Comment: Your request is probably faulty and the server sends you an error page that's html and therefore begins with an `<`.

Comment: @JBNizet, yes, I opened the Network tab and watched that there is no response, it indicates in big letters: Failed to load response data. But if it really works, what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

Well,

Now, at least, I could guess what's happening.

For some strange circumstance, in Chrome was activated Development mode and when switch it off, the page works fine and no error arises now.